# Oauth for open source code

Tags: open-source, oauth, google-chrome-extension, tumblr

I am looking at creating a *good* google chrome extension for tumblr.

Now tumblr uses Oauth as it's authentication method.

So my question becomes.

Do I:

- Distribute a single key with the application and hope people are nice enough to not use it for illegitimate purposes.
- Put in the options the ability for a user to enter their own key, hence asking each user to register an application.
- Create an intermediary on my server that makes the actual request.
- Something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also had to consider this for [my Template extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf) when using [OAuth](http://oauth.net) to communicate with the [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) URL shortener service on the user's behalf.

After reading Chrome's [OAuth tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) I managed to implement this simply using the following;

```
ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
    access_url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    app_name: chrome.i18n.getMessage('app_name'),
    authorize_url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    consumer_key: 'anonymous',
    consumer_secret: 'anonymous',
    request_url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener'
});
```

This is surrounded by quite a bit of logic due to the complexity of the extension but this results in the user simply being shown a page (on a new tab) the first time they attempt to shorten a URL using my [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) implementation. Here the user can decide to allow/deny the authentication. Since this is only done once (unless the user later removes it from their list of authorized applications) I thought this was fine and my users seem to agree.

I did also provide an option to toggle [OAuth](http://oauth.net) on/off but I'm guessing this will always be required for the [tumblr API](http://tumblr.com/docs/api). On that note I must admit I'm not familiar with that particular API so I'm afraid I can't help you further.

Comment: But how does this answer the question of: how do you/do you bother protecting your app key from others?